# I need some support with my piece of code (c++)

Tags: c++

I have a school task that I need to complete. I'm an entry level programmer, really just for some school stuff so it isn't that complicated. I just need to find out, what's the easiest way to cover all of the answers. Here is my code.

```
float e,d, m,n,d, no;

cout << "Enter the numerator of the first radian or if it doesn't have one, type no: ";
cin >> e;
cout << "Enter the denominator of the first radian or if it doesn't have one, type no: ";
cin >> m;
cout << "Enter the numerator of the second radian or if it doesn't have one, type no: ";
cin >> d;
cout << "Enter the denominator of the second radian or if it doesn't have one, type no: ";
cin >> n;
```

Then I need to solve an equation with them.
I would like it to work in every possible way but it's diffcult to cover all of the possible answers. Any tips, how should I start. I know it's probably confusing, I don't know if it's correct or not.

Comment: Input *no* is not a `float`. you probably need to read string, and parse afterward.

Comment: You try to declare twice `d`...

Comment: Oh yeah, I can see. I also changed the input. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How to read number or some text from stream.

When you read a number, but something else is encounter, stream is set int invalid state (`failbit` flag is set). So to handle case first you have to clear error flag and then read a string.

Since you are expecting "no" text so if something else is encounter then `failbit` flag can be restored.

```cpp
std::istream& read_value_or_NO(std::istream& in, std::optional<double>& x)
{
    double y;
    if (in >> y) {
        x = y;
        return in;
    }
    std::string s;
    in.clear();
    x = {};
    if (in >> s && s == "no") {
        return in;
    }
    in.setstate(std::ios::failbit); // error if it is not "no" string
    return in;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rPdTTMbvT

Comment: not the downvoter, I like the solution, but it needs more explanation. Especially how to reset `std::cin` in case of "wrong response" may not be that obvious.

Comment: Yeah. To be honest that was the last thing I wanted to try because I know that you guys are busy with "real cases". This is my first attempt on this site. Since my main subject is not programming and I'm a ninth grader, I know the basics only. Like nothing more. But thanks for the support you can leave this thing as it is.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 thanks for feedback I've added some explanation.